# Yii renders only one page without layout

Tags: php, layout, yii, themes, render

I have a weird problem. I copied my website into production environment (from windows to ubuntu). I correct few big/small letter issues and app started to work fine. Until I entered one page that looks like it's being rendered without layout. There is no error. 
Also - firebug shows no css styles or anything. At HTML source there is lack of layout code too.
What could be the reason of that?

EDIT:

controller part:

```
$dataProvider = Projects::model()->getInviteProjectsProvider();
$this->render('invite', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
));
```

It returns CActiveDataProvider.

View:

```
<?php

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Projekty' => array('admin'),
    'Zapraszanie',
);

$this->renderPartial('_allMenu');

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->module->assetsUrl; ?>/css/projects.css"/> 

<h1>Projekty aktywne - zapraszanie</h1>
<?php   

    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
        'id' => 'invite-grid',
        'type' => 'striped condensed',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'rowCssClassExpression' => '($data->leftCustomers<100) ? "error":""',
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'idProject',
                'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '60px', 'style' => 'text-align: right;', 'class' => 'gridIdColumn'),
            ),
            'name',
            array(
                'name' => 'leftCustomers',
                'header' => 'Pozostało <i class="icon-info-sign" rel="tooltipbootstrap" data-original-title="Gdy wartość ta jest mniejsza niż 100 - rekord jest podświetlony na czerwono"/>',
            ),
            'confirmStart',
            'presentationDate',
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbRelationalColumn',
                'name' => 'Statystyki',
                'value' => '"Pokaż"',
                'url' => $this->createUrl('dynamicProjectStats')
            ),
            array(
                'header' => 'Postęp <i class="icon-info-sign" rel="tooltipbootstrap" data-original-title="Liczba zaproszeń / Limit zaproszeń"/>',
                'value' => function($data)
                {
                    $prc = round(($data->projectMaxInvites > 0) ? ($data->projectInvites)/ $data->projectMaxInvites * 100 : 0, 2);
                    Controller::widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress', array(
                        'percent' => $prc,
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'style' => 'height: 20px; margin-bottom: -20px',
                            'rel' => 'tooltipbootstrap',
                            'data-original-title' => $prc." %",
                        ),
                    ));
                },
            ),
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'style' => 'width: 40px;',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'header' => '',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 43px'),
                'value' => function($data)
                {
                    $this->renderPartial('partials/_actionMenu', array('idProject' => $data->idProject, 'activated' => true, 'afterAction' => 'removeActiveProject'));
                }
            ),
            array(
                'header' => '',
                'value' => function($data)
                {
                    $this->renderPartial('partials/_statMenu', array('idProject' => $data->idProject, 'showIcon' => true));
                }
            ),
        )
    ));
?>
```

I noticed that if I comment out the columns where `function($data)` is used - it shows fine. When I leave it - there is no layout displayed.

EDIT2:
Maybe I should notice the fact that inside `partials/_statMenu` and `partials/_actionMenu` there is a `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup` widget rendered.

Comment: Please post the code you use to render that view (piece of controller action where you call render() method)

Comment: I left only the last column but I commented `$this->renderPartial('pqrtials/_statMenu'...` and it works. It seems like rendering widget/partial inside the column using `function($data)` breaks layout. It's weird that in Windows it works.

Comment: Try Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial instead. Will it work?

Comment: You are good :) It works great. you should add it as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial(...)
```

Instead of:

```
$this->renderPartial(...)
```